# Refreshing Items in wheelnav.js

Tags: javascript, wheelnav.js

I'm using the excellent wheelnav.js but i am having trouble getting the icons to update

I originally have 2, but want it update based on a selection.  The number of items is determined by a variable that will change.  So to start with I have (some stuff omitted for clarity)...

```
var wheelIcons = [icon.apple, icon.android];
mainNavWheel = new wheelnav('mainNavWheel');
mainNavWheel.createWheel(wheelIcons)
```

works perfectly, but on the click of a button i want to update the number of items...

```
function setWheelItems(){
        wheelIcons = [icon.font, icon.resize2, icon.lock, icon.star, icon.pallete];
    mainNavWheel.refreshWheel();
    console.log("set wheel items");
}
```

I know the function gets called due to my console log, but nothing happens to the wheel.  Am I missing something really obvious to get the number of items to update ??

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use removeWheel() to achieve your needs.

```
var wheel;
var wheelIcons;

window.onload = function () {
  wheelIcons = [icon.apple, icon.android];
  wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");
  wheel.createWheel(wheelIcons);
};

function setWheelItems(){
  wheel.removeWheel();
  wheelIcons = [icon.font, icon.resize2, icon.lock, icon.star, icon.pallete];
  wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");
  wheel.createWheel(wheelIcons);
}
```

Here is a [JS Bin for demo](http://jsbin.com/hakeka/edit?js,output).

Comment: ahh that's great, how daft of me, thanks a lot for your help on this awesome  project